# Is there any plan on making comments as rich text

Tags: feature-request

Today I commented in the answers column and was pointed out that it is a wrong process.

Just curious to know if comments would be made a rich text too so that line breaks code highlight and other cooler stuff would be available too when commenting

Answer (score 8):

I deleted the answer in question after it was flagged just to keep things nice and tidy, but for future reference there is some minimal formatting available in the comments box. The syntax is shown if you click the help link next to the comment box.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Comments have limited formatting because they are simply a lightweight means of asking an author for clarifications or to issue guidance to help improve the post. Comments aren't supposed to be for rich-text interactions (as you found out). If we added features to make commenting much more capable, that would make it *easier* for folks to use them for purposes beyond which they are intended (like answering questions, etc).

So comments are conspicuously a second-class citizen. And that is by design.